# Closing a question as marking duplicate after close vote retract

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close

I have closed the question stating `too broad` and later I found a similar question and wanted to close that post as `duplicate`. So, for this I needed to retract the close vote. Now, when I try to close the question stating `duplicate`, it says:

> You have already voted to close this question.

And I cannot close the question. I think this should be revised?

I know retracting close votes and doing close votes again (stating other reason) is not good idea. But it should allow to close the question as `duplicate`. What do you think?

Comment: Isn't there a warning for this when you retract your vote?